# How to construct xml element with attribute using python zeep?

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

I'm trying to contact SOAP api with xml defined as: http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/EETXMLSchema.xsd . I've used this question ( [How to construct SOAP message with pysimplesoap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846470/how-to-construct-soap-message-with-pysimplesoap) ) and created following code in python :

```
import zeep
import datetime

wsdl = 'http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/EETServiceSOAP.wsdl'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl,transport=transport)


daco = client.service.OdeslaniTrzby(Hlavicka = {
'uuid_zpravy' : '1',
'dat_odesl' : datetime.datetime.now(),
'prvni_zaslani' : '1',
'overeni' : "true"

}, Data={
    'dic_popl' : '',
    #'dic_poverujiciho' : '',
    'id_provoz' : '151151',
    'id_pokl' : '102',
    'porad_cis' : '1',
    'dat_trzby' : datetime.datetime.now(),
    'celk_trzba' : '100',
    'rezim' : '0'

}, KontrolniKody = {
'pkp' : {'digest': 'SHA256', 'cipher' : 'RSA2048', 'encoding' : 'base64'},
'bkp' : {'digest': 'SHA1', 'encoding' : 'base16'}

})
```

My question is following, the part with "KontrolniKody" at the end contains pkp and bkp elements. Pkp should have attributes digest, cipher and encoding (not sure if I put that correctly inside) and it should also contain the ~340 chars of generated code but I'm not sure where or how to put that in the element.

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks for the help either way.