# TypeError in SOAP Request (using pysimplesoap)

Tags: python, xml, soap, wsdl, pysimplesoap

I'm trying to get relevant information from a SOAP service from the Dutch government land register ([WSDL here](http://www1.kadaster.nl/1/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101/verzoekTotInformatie-2.1.wsdl)) with [PySimpleSoap](https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap). So far I managed to connect and request information about a specific property with the following code:

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
client = SoapClient(wsdl='http://www1.kadaster.nl/1/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101/verzoekTotInformatie-2.1.wsdl', username='xxx', password='xxx', trace=True)

response = client.VerzoekTotInformatie(
    Aanvraag={
        'berichtversie': '4.7',  # Refers to the schema version
        'klantReferentie': klantReferentie,  # A reference we can set ourselves.
        'productAanduiding': '1185',  # a four-digit code referring to whether the response should be in "XML" (1185), "PDF" (1191) or "XML and PDF" (1057).
        'Ingang': {
            'Object': {
                'IMKAD_KadastraleAanduiding': {
                    'gemeente': 'ARNHEM AC',  # municipality
                    'sectie': 'AC',  # section code
                    'perceelnummer': '1234'  # Lot number
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

This "kinda" works. I set `trace=True` so I get extensive log messages, and in those log messages I see a humongous xml output ([paste here](http://pastebin.com/eamQzGSt)) which pretty much includes all info which I request. BUT, I also get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    'perceelnummer': perceelnummer
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 181, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.wsdl_call(attr, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 346, in wsdl_call
    return self.wsdl_call_with_args(method, args, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 372, in wsdl_call_with_args
    resp = response('Body', ns=soap_uri).children().unmarshall(output)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py", line 433, in unmarshall
    value = children and children.unmarshall(fn, strict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py", line 433, in unmarshall
    value = children and children.unmarshall(fn, strict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py", line 433, in unmarshall
    value = children and children.unmarshall(fn, strict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py", line 380, in unmarshall
    raise TypeError("Tag: %s invalid (type not found)" % (name,))
TypeError: Tag: IMKAD_Perceel invalid (type not found)
```

As far as I understand, this means that the `IMKAD_Perceel` tag cannot be understood by the [simplexml parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplexml/0.6.1) which (I'm guessing) is because it could not read/find the definition of this tag in the wdsl file.

So I checked the (enormous amount of) log messages from parsing the wsdl file, and that shows these lines:

```
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:Parsing Element element: IMKAD_Perceel
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:Processing element IMKAD_Perceel element
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:IMKAD_Perceel has no children!
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:complexContent/simpleType/element IMKAD_Perceel = IMKAD_Perceel
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:Parsing Element complexType: IMKAD_Perceel
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:Processing element IMKAD_Perceel complexType
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:complexContent/simpleType/element IMKAD_Perceel = IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak
DEBUG:pysimplesoap.helpers:Processing element IMKAD_Perceel complexType
```

I guess these lines mean that the `IMKAD_Perceel` definition is empty. So I used [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to introspect [the WSDL file](http://www1.kadaster.nl/1/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101/verzoekTotInformatie-2.1.wsdl), in which I found [an url to this .xsd-file](http://www1.kadaster.nl/1/schemas/kik-inzage/20141101/ip-kadastraalberichtobject-2.1.xsd) in which I find a definition of the `IMKAD_Perceel`:

```
<xs:element name="IMKAD_Perceel" 
    substitutionGroup="ipkbo:IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak" 
    type="ipkbo:IMKAD_Perceel"
    />
```

The tag indeed seems to be closing itself, which means it is empty. Is this the reason that pysimplesoap thinks that `IMKAD_Perceel` is not defined? Why can't it simply interpret the xml and return it back as a dict? (as said before, the full xml output I receive is in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/eamQzGSt)).

Does anybody know how I can make pysimplesoap interpret the xml and convert it to a dict, regardless whether it adheres to the wsdl?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: We can't reproduce the error since we are not authorized to use this service. I think it's better for you to contact the provider of this web service.

Comment: @skyline75489 - I added a paste of the xml I receive back: http://pastebin.com/eamQzGSt . Does this help to debug?

Comment: The response you got seems to be OK, even it complains about `type error`. Is there any problem with the response?

Comment: @skyline75489 - The response is fine. It is just that I can't do anything with the response because pysimplesoap gives that error. Any idea how I can solve that error? I guess the problem lies somewhere in the simplexml implementation. The line where it goes wrong is this: https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap/blob/master/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py#L380 . I tried setting `strict` to `False`, but then `IMKAD_Perceel` becomes  `'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'`

Comment: `I can't do anything with the response` Doing what exactly will cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `pysimplesoap` is not capable of dealing with `substitutionGroup` in xml schema.

You can see that in the xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="IMKAD_Perceel" 
substitutionGroup="ipkbo:IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak" 
type="ipkbo:IMKAD_Perceel"
/>
```

There is this `substitutionGroup`, which means that `IMKAD_Perceel` and `IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak` is the same thing and substitutable for each other.

In the soap schema, this particular part of response is defined as:

```
<xs:complexType name="BerichtGegevens">
 <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation>Inhoud van het bericht.</xs:documentation>    
 </xs:annotation>
 <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="ipkbo:IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element ref="ipkbo:Recht" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><xs:element ref="ipkbo:IMKAD_Stuk" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xs:element ref="ipkbo:IMKAD_Persoon" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xs:element ref="ipkbo:GemeentelijkeRegistratie" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, you can see the actual response is like:

```
<ipkbo:BerichtGegevens>
  <ipkbo:IMKAD_Perceel>...</ipkbo:IMKAD_Perceel>
  <ipkbo:Recht>...</ipkbo:Recht>
  <ipkbo:IMKAD_AangebodenStuk>...</ipkbo:IMKAD_AangebodenStuk>
  <ipkbo:IMKAD_Persoon>...</ipkbo:IMKAD_Persoon>
</ipkbo:BerichtGegevens>
```

Then `pysimplesoap` seems to get confused and fail to get correct type of response.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough analysis and explanation of the source of the error. Would you possibly also have any clue how I could actually solve it? The source of simplexml is included with the pysimplesource (https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap/blob/master/pysimplesoap/simplexml.py). Would you have any idea how I can edit that to get `substitutionGroup`s working?

Comment: You can try hacking it using `types['IMKAD_Perceel'] = types['IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak']`. Just add this to the `unmarshall` function at the beginning of it .

Comment: If I try that I get a Key Error:  `File "pysimplesoap/simplexml.py", line 325, in unmarshall
    types['IMKAD_Perceel'] = types['IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak']
KeyError: u'IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak'`. `IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak` is supposedly also not loaded in the types. Any other idea?

Comment: Well, you can't just do this. Because this function is called for EVERY SimpleXMLElement. I would recommend adding `if 'IMKAD_OnroerendeZaak' in types`

Comment: Since that results in many things not rendered I decided the just return the raw xml as a string and use [xmltpdict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) to convert it and then clean it further. It's not pretty, but it works for now. Thanks a million for helping me understand a lot more!